# Fixing jupyter notebook on AWS

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to set up jupyter notebook to run on AWS, I'm followed this guide - https://medium.com/@alexjsanchez/python-3-notebooks-on-aws-ec2-in-15-mostly-easy-steps-2ec5e662c6c6.

It worked but I now realise that every time I launch jupyter on my local machine, it asks for a password, also the password saved no longer works effectively locking me out of jupyter:
[image]

I presume its because I set up the ssh connection to port 8888 which is what jupyter uses by default. However, I've removed the ssh config file in step 10 but no change. [image]

---

I'm stumped as to why jupyter no longer launches correctly, does anyone have any ideas on how I correct this?

I've also noticed that a token is given when launching jupyter from an EC2 instance
[image]

but in my case non is given

```
#Launching jupyter in notebook from EC2 enviornment
(base) [ec2-user@ip-172-31-59-151 ~]$ jupyter lab --no-browser
[I 14:49:49.917 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 14:49:49.917 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab
[I 14:49:49.919 LabApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/ec2-user
[I 14:49:49.919 LabApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.1.4 is running at:
[I 14:49:49.919 LabApp] http://localhost:8888/
[I 14:49:49.920 LabApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

Comment: Are you wanting to now use your local jupyter notebook server instead of the cloud version you set up? If so, I don't see anything in this tutorial that would cause your local jupyter notebook server to ask for a password. Basically the set up in this tutorial has you use `9999` port for your new cloud jupyter notebook server and `8888` for your existing local. It changes nothing about your local jupyter environment at all.

Comment: No I just want to launch jupyter notebook on my local machine as normal to do some work. I also should of mentioned I think I used 8888 for both but Im unsure how to reverse this.

Comment: When you perform this step on your local machine `ssh -NfL 9999:localhost:8888 ec2` as long as that connection is alive when you visit url `http://localhost:9999` in your browser it will route that `9999` traffic out to the ec2 instance. That's the only step here that maps ports around. If you instead decided to tunnel on port 8888 (locally) you would have ran: `ssh -NfL 8888:localhost:8888 ec2`. If that's the case, `ctrl-c` that ssh connection and do it properly using a port that isn't `8888` like `ssh -NfL 9999:localhost:8888 ec2` Then when you visit `http://localhost:8888` it will be local.

Comment: Also... as an experiment if you your `ssh -NfL 9999:localhost:8888 ec2` command is running in a terminal somewhere, just go shut it down. That will completely sever the connection out to your ec2 instance and then you know for certain that any localhost url you hit will be pointing to your own machine. Ultimately, while this tutorial breezes right through it with a sentence or two, it would be a good idea to understand ssh tunneling if you continue in this direction. Once it clicks for you this will make a lot more sense.

Comment: @JNevill Thanks for the advice, when I run `ssh -NfL 9999:localhost:8888 ec2` I get `ssh: Could not resolve hostname ec2: Name or service not known` message . How would i check if the command is running in a terminal as you mentioned? I think my best bet is to sever any connections and start afresh. As you mention I'll then get back to porting after a bit of schooling.

Comment: I assume you get that error because you deleted your ssh config file. Get that created once again and then you can once again tunnel to ec2 using that command. Again though... hitting `localhost:8888` in your browser WITHOUT running that command ensures that you are truly hitting your local computer Jupyter instance and you shouldn't get the password issue (assuming you don't use a password for you local jupyter notebook instance).

Comment: @JNevill Ok the issue is that I am getting the password issue without the ssh connection (deleted it). I don't use a password for my local instance so its weird that the password requirement is still there. Any other ideas?

Comment: That's where I'm not sure what is happening. If that SSH connection/command is not running and you hit `localhost:8888` and it's asking for password that means your local instance of Jupyter Notebook is password protected... again there is nothing in that tutorial that would cause that behavior. I would, as a next step, check your local version of `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json` to see if there is a password setting in there. I believe you can just delete that, restart jupyter locally and try again with the browser.

Comment: @JNevill Its a weird one for sure. I checked the local file and its just an empty dictionary so I don't think its that. Also went back onto my windows side and everythings normal, using port 8888 jupyter launches locally without password request.  Apart from deleting the shh.config file is there any other method of verifying that there's no outgoing ssh connecting to port 8888?